# Inserting nested entities using Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, annotations, entity

I am trying to figure out how to correctly insert into the database several entities which has another entities as fields, and seems that in hibernate it is a bit non trivial task. It works fine when I have everything ordered and neat, but as soon as they are cross linked, it is not working as desired. I assume I'm missing some required annotations to make it work, but after several hours googling I can't find anything suitable to solve it in prompt manner.

My current entities set up this way I have a student and

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

And I have a classroom which holds a Student entity linked by its id

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ClassRoom {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_student"))
    private Student student;

    private String dateCreated;
}
```

And I have a json which works perfectly when I try to store it into db:

```
{
   "dateCreated":"17",
   "body":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "student":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"petya",
            "hibernateLazyInitializer":{

            }
         },
         "dateCreated":"17"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "student":{
            "id":2,
            "name":"petrya",
            "hibernateLazyInitializer":{

            }
         },
         "dateCreated":"17"
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "student":{
            "id":3,
            "name":"slon",
            "hibernateLazyInitializer":{

            }
         },
         "dateCreated":"17"
      }
   ]
}

Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_1_0_, student0_.name as name2_1_0_ from json_schema.student student0_ where student0_.id=?
Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_1_0_, student0_.name as name2_1_0_ from json_schema.student student0_ where student0_.id=?
Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_1_0_, student0_.name as name2_1_0_ from json_schema.student student0_ where student0_.id=?
Hibernate: select classroom0_.id as id1_0_0_, classroom0_.date_created as date_cre2_0_0_, classroom0_.student_id as student_3_0_0_ from json_schema.class_room classroom0_ where classroom0_.id=?
Hibernate: select classroom0_.id as id1_0_0_, classroom0_.date_created as date_cre2_0_0_, classroom0_.student_id as student_3_0_0_ from json_schema.class_room classroom0_ where classroom0_.id=?
Hibernate: select classroom0_.id as id1_0_0_, classroom0_.date_created as date_cre2_0_0_, classroom0_.student_id as student_3_0_0_ from json_schema.class_room classroom0_ where classroom0_.id=?
Hibernate: update json_schema.class_room set date_created=?, student_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update json_schema.class_room set date_created=?, student_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update json_schema.class_room set date_created=?, student_id=? where id=?
```

But once I try to save second classroom entry which links to third student for example like this one:

```
{
   "dateCreated":"10",
   "body":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "student":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"petya",
            "hibernateLazyInitializer":{

            }
         },
         "dateCreated":"10"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "student":{
            "id":3,
            "name":"slon",
            "hibernateLazyInitializer":{

            }
         },
         "dateCreated":"10"
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "student":{
            "id":2,
            "name":"petrya",
            "hibernateLazyInitializer":{

            }
         },
         "dateCreated":"10"
      }
   ]
}

Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_1_0_, student0_.name as name2_1_0_ from json_schema.student student0_ where student0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into json_schema.student (name) values (?)
Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_1_0_, student0_.name as name2_1_0_ from json_schema.student student0_ where student0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into json_schema.student (name) values (?)
Hibernate: update json_schema.student set name=? where id=?
Hibernate: select classroom0_.id as id1_0_0_, classroom0_.date_created as date_cre2_0_0_, classroom0_.student_id as student_3_0_0_ from json_schema.class_room classroom0_ where classroom0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into json_schema.class_room (date_created, student_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select classroom0_.id as id1_0_0_, classroom0_.date_created as date_cre2_0_0_, classroom0_.student_id as student_3_0_0_ from json_schema.class_room classroom0_ where classroom0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into json_schema.class_room (date_created, student_id) values (?, ?)
```

It breaks with:

ERROR: insert or update on table "class_room" violates foreign key constraint "fk_student"
  Detail: Key (student_id)=(3) is not present in table "student".

It might be the logic I'm implementing, I'm trying to store them this way:

```
final ClassRoom[] classRooms = objectMapper.readValue(parser, ClassRoom[].class);
        final List<ClassRoom> classRoomList = Arrays.asList(classRooms);
        final List<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final ClassRoom classRoom : classRoomList) {
            studentsList.add(classRoom.getStudent());

        }
        studentRepo.saveAll(studentsList);
        classRoomRepo.saveAll(classRoomList);
```

But I don't know how to separately store students first, and only after store classRooms.
 Appreciate any help. Hopefully will solve it with time, if so, will post an answer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your approache to id is `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`, while your list of students and classroom both has id populated in advance. If you want to keep those id coming in json, remove  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` annotation.